# How can I store the status in an array after concatenating

Tags: php, arrays, concatenation

Example: (if the status can be: 'done', on_going', 'to_verify')

for loop starts here --------

I used

```
$status .= $status;
```

and if I perform

```
echo  $status;
```

it will give me `'doneon_goingdoneto_verify'`

for loop endshere --------

I would want to perform something based on the status like if there's 'on_going' status then set

```
$on_going =1;
```

However, if I performed concat, I can't check status by status. Any suggestion how I can do this?

Comment: Why do you even need to concatenate in the first place?

Comment: I can also store strings(the status) in array after split() if I just add delimiters when I concatenate. Anyone knows how to do this?

Comment: Well in that case store it in an array right away, instead of first putting it in a string and then splitting. See fcingolani's answer below.

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
$statuses = array();

foreach($foo as $bar){
  $statuses[] = $bar;
}

if(in_array('on_going', $statuses)){
  echo "It's on going!";
}
?>
```

This will allow you to have simultaneous statuses, like "on going" and "delayed" at the same time.

Answer (score 1):

How about:

```
$on_going = FALSE;
$statuses = '';

foreach(...)
{
    if($status == 'on_going') { $on_going = TRUE; }
    $statuses .= $status;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach($array as $status) [
  $$status = 1; // creates a variable for each array element.
}
```